# how to use sinon to test two await in a line

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I want to stub some codes that have two await in line.

```js
import { githubApi } from "../../githubApi";

export async function getMembers (projectName) {
  const members = await (await githubApi(projectName)).projects
    .members({
      id: 'xxx'
    });
  return members;
}
```

how can I use sinon to mock `await (await githubApi(projectName)).projects
    .member` ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the API in the example seems difficult to test I will assume that has been taken into account and that `githubApi` is in some why mock-able.

```
let membersFake = sinon.fake().resolves([member1, member2, member3]);
let githubApiFake = sinon.fake().resolves({
  projects: {
    members: membersFake
  }
});
```

Then you can replace the `githubApi` with the fake. Now if `githubApi` is not easily mock-able and you don't own that file maybe it is worth looking into some dependency injection.

```
export async function getMembers (projectName, githubApi = githubApi) {
  ...
}
```

In this way you can pass in your fake directly when testing the function in a unit test but in your app code it will default to the real one imported.